# JSON y ASP Classic

Tags: json, asp

Necesito aplicar este codigo fuente : [URL](http://apidocs.yotpo.com/v1.0/docs/yotpo-authentication)

Puedo utilizar [json](/questions/tagged/json) y [asp](/questions/tagged/asp) Classic he buscado varias librerías pero no consigo realizar el método **POST** con [json](/questions/tagged/json) utilizando este lenguaje.

Conoce alguien alguna libreria que me pueda ayudar?
Alguien a utilizado [json](/questions/tagged/json) con este lenguaje de programación.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con jquery o javascript para hacer la llamada. Yo suelo usar esta funcion

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:" dirección de llmada ",
                data: {  variables que se pasan },
                success: function(data) {

                }
            });
```